# DB2: Setting Integrity in parent-child order

Tags: sql, shell, db2, relational-database, sh

I am trying to write a script (shell+DB2) which sets integrity of all tables in database.
I used below dynamic SQL to generate a script and executed it:

```
db2 -x "select 'SET INTEGRITY FOR '|| TABSCHEMA ||'.'||TABNAME || ' IMMEDIATE CHECKED;' from SYSCAT.TABLES where STATUS='C' and type='T'" > set_integrity.sql
```

It works fine but the issue is when tables have relationships (parent-child tables).
It gives error SQL3608N "cannot check integrity of child table when parent is in set integrity pending"

Please let me know how I can modify my SQL or write a shell script / stored procedure such that it sets integrity in parent-child order. My final goal is to have zero tables in check-pending / set integrity pending state.

Please help.
Thanks!!

Comment: To make sure I understand, do you get that error when you're trying to *build* the SQL statements, or when you're trying to execute them?

Comment: I get that error when I execute the script generated by the mentioned dynamic SQL for those tables which occur before their parents in script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly look at `SYSCAT.REFERENCES` to identify the parent-child order, but you'll end up needing to write a recursive query if you have more than 1 level of dependencies.  Not to mention that if you have 2 co-dependent tables (i.e. table1 has a foreign key on table2; and table2 has a foreign key on table 1), it's much more difficult to generate this list.

I find that it's generally easier to just ignore the failed `SET INTEGRITY` statements and repeat the process until there are no tables left:

```
db2 -x "select 'SET INTEGRITY FOR '|| TABSCHEMA ||'.'||TABNAME || ' IMMEDIATE CHECKED;' from SYSCAT.TABLES where STATUS='C' and type='T'" > set_integrity.sql

tabcnt=$(wc -l set_integrity.sql)
while [[ ${tabcnt} -gt 0 ]] ; do
    db2 -tf set_integrity.sql

    # look for more tables in check pending state
    db2 -x "select 'SET INTEGRITY FOR '|| TABSCHEMA ||'.'||TABNAME || ' IMMEDIATE CHECKED;' from SYSCAT.TABLES where STATUS='C' and type='T'" > set_integrity.sql
    tabcnt=$(wc -l set_integrity.sql)
done
```

This isn't pretty or elegant but it works.

Comment: Thanksfor your help... @Ian Bjorhovde

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
db2 << EOL
with refs (parent, child, levels) as \
      (select reftabname, tabname, 1 from syscat.references where tabschema = 'DEV' \
      union all \
      select reftabname, tabname, levels+1 \
        from refs r, syscat.references s where s.tabname = r.parent and s.tabschema = 'DEV') \
select 'set integrity for ' || st.name || ' with immediate check' \
    from (select parent, max(levels) lv from refs group by parent) rf \
      right join sysibm.systables st on rf.parent = st.name \
      where st.status = 'C' and st.type = 'T' and st.creator = 'DEV' \
      order by coalesce(rf.lv,0) desc
EOL
```